# Bar Button Item No Corner Radius

Tags: swift, navbar, cornerradius

I am trying to give this bar button item label a green background and then some corner radius.

```
    utcLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20)
    utcLbl.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())) UTC"
    utcItem.customView = utcLbl
    utcLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    utcLbl.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    utcLbl.textAlignment = .center
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([utcItem], animated: true)
```

here is the code and a picture

[image]

any help on getting the green background to have a corner radius.

Comment: it would help if you added some tags.  I don't know what language this is

Comment: @JohnLord there is `swift` tag

Comment: Try setting clipstoBounds and/or masksToBounds properties to true

Comment: @emrepun thanks but it didn't work. Maybe bc its a barButtonItem?? Any other ideas??

Comment: it looks like it worked from the answer below? :) @RileyLunz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clipToBounds or masksToBounds

```
utcLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20)
utcLbl.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())) UTC"
utcItem.customView = utcLbl
utcLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
utcLbl.layer.cornerRadius = 20
utcLbl.textAlignment = .center
utcLbl.layer.masksToBounds = true // Or utcLbl.clipsToBounds = true
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([utcItem], animated: true)
```

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck

Comment: Does it make a differnence which one I use? They both seem to work

Comment: Both are the same in terms of functionality. But just to quickly explain: clipsToBounds does the job on subViews while masksToBounds does the job on subLayers.

Comment: Is one faster or more efficient @Galo Torres Sevilla?

Comment: Both are pretty much the same. Same amount of calculations and same amount of work in terms of view refresh. Now, if you start talking about efficiency, I usually try to avoid `cornerRadius` mostly because of the amount of calculations that it requires, and if you consider the refresh rate of the screen and time it has to display everything in the main queue, it is not that efficient and can cause performance problems if you use it too much. If you only have one button it should be ok. But if you are gonna constantly use it, I would suggest you create a masking layer and subclass UILabel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186228/discussion-between-riley-lunz-and-galo-torres-sevilla).